# Beautifly / Tidy (Javascript) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm currently giving Visual Studio Code a try. Overall I like the user experience however I can't find some of the things I'm very much used to, in sublime (with the help of extensions.)

One of them is beautify code (or tidy up) - is there any way to do this for JavaScript in Visual Studio Code?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to beautify the code, you can just press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `format code` or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

It correctly indents my code so it seems like that is what you are looking for, if not you might want to give an example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the shortcuts to beautify the code in Visual Studio Code:

- On Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- On Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- On Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

As per the Programming language (PHP, HTML, JavaScript, ASP, JSP, etc.) it will ask you to install a package, after installation you can use above shortcuts.